# SugarCRM changing module icon

Tags: sugarcrm

So I am to change the icons for my custom module. My module is of the file type and I want the icons to be that of the sales type. I need the module to be of file type in order to have the upload file field however.

So I have tried replacing all the files for my custom module in custom/themes/default/images/ with files from a custom sales module but that hasn't worked.

I have also tried to edit the menu.php file but it doesn't exist so I couldn't.

I'm using Sugar 6.5.5 CE edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the problem I think was that it needed a quick repair and rebuild.